# How to make a button in pygame display and update images?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a button in pygame. It is supposed to display three new images everytime it is clicked. Everything works, except these 3 images only appear while the button is clicked on. The code to display the images is below, it is part of a larger while loop which continues infinitely for now. How can i make it so that the images stay until the button is pressed again and new images appear? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos ()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed ()

    element = -1
    if 1120 > mouse [0] > 865 and 330 > mouse [1] > 250:
        screen.blit (dice_button_light, (870, 250))

        if click [0] == 1:
            dice_choices = Dice.dice_choice()
            print(dice_choices)


            element = -1
            for i in dice_choices:
                element += 1
                x = 750
                if element == 1:
                    x += 100
                if element == 2:
                    x += 200
                if i == 1:
                    screen.blit (dice1,(x,100))   
                elif i == 2:
                    screen.blit (dice2,(x,100))
                elif i == 3:
                    screen.blit (dice3,(x,100))
                elif i == 4:
                    screen.blit (dice4,(x,100))
                elif i == 5:
                    screen.blit (dice5,(x,100))
                elif i == 6:
                    screen.blit (dice6,(x,100))


    else:
        screen.blit (dice_button, (870, 250))
```

Answer (score 0):

To cycle through different images, you can put them into a list and whenever the button rect is clicked, increment an `index` variable that represents the current image. In your while loop just use the index to get the correct image out of the list.

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


# Three images.
IMG1 = pg.Surface((100, 100))
IMG1.fill((240, 240, 240))
pg.draw.circle(IMG1, (0, 0, 0), (50, 50), 10)
IMG2 = pg.Surface((100, 100))
IMG2.fill((240, 240, 240))
pg.draw.circle(IMG2, (0, 0, 0), (25, 25), 10)
pg.draw.circle(IMG2, (0, 0, 0), (75, 75), 10)
IMG3 = pg.Surface((100, 100))
IMG3.fill((240, 240, 240))
pg.draw.circle(IMG3, (0, 0, 0), (20, 20), 10)
pg.draw.circle(IMG3, (0, 0, 0), (50, 50), 10)
pg.draw.circle(IMG3, (0, 0, 0), (80, 80), 10)
# Put the images into a list or tuple.
IMAGES = [IMG1, IMG2, IMG3]


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    bg_color = pg.Color(30, 40, 60)
    # Use this rect for the collision detection and blitting.
    img_rect = IMG1.get_rect(topleft=(200, 200))
    img_index = 0
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if img_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    img_index += 1
                    # Modulo to cycle between 0, 1, 2.
                    img_index %= len(IMAGES)

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        # Use the index to get the current image and blit
        # it at the img_rect (topleft) position.
        screen.blit(IMAGES[img_index], img_rect)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```